# gente alguém me ajuda com essa função do visualg

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

eu estou tentando usar as funções prontas do visualg, para ler um nome, dizer o código da 3 letra, assim como mostra-lo, mas o problema é esta dando erro direto

escreval("esse é o código da terceira letra do seu nome: ",copia(minusc(x),asc(x),compr(x),3))

ai está o comando, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Boa noite felipe, não consegui entender sua pergunta, mas já tentou fazer um array e retornar o 3 elemento ?

Comment: ola luiz boa noite e obrigado por responder, eu estava tentando usar multiplas funções do visualg para o tipo caractere, para mostrar a terceira letra de um nome e o seu código (asc), mas esta dando erro direto eu acho que tem haver com a posição de uma das funções só não consigo descobrir qual.